# Java. TreeSet successor

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, tree, set

I am interested in such a question: as we know, *Red-Black tree* provides efficient implementation of such operations as *successor* (the first element higher that entry) and *predecessor* , i.e. in log - time.
In **Java documentation** is written that for providing such operation as successor you may merely use subSet and then took the least element in the **subSet**. But is it log-time? If it is, what is the implementation of **subSet**?(I am interested in the algorithm, so it may be just few words, not necessary code)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question: HashSet does have methods `lower(E e)` and `higher(E e)`.

Comment: By the way, if you use an IDE (I use NetBeans) you can see the code of a class or method of the Java platform with one click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just read the code to see how it works.

I believe subSet is O(log N) A more natural approach would be to use the `lower(E)` and `higher(E)` methods which is designed to do this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html